# When importing files using google cloud; the output gives me a TransportError and RefreshError

Tags: python, dataframe, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, kaggle

When using `pd.read_csv` I get a long output  and the error says:

```
RefreshError: Failed to retrieve http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/?recursive=true from the Google Compute Engine metadata service. Compute Engine Metadata server unavailable
```

I import library and call file using `df.head()` and then when I want to give the `df_url` its `Gs:function` to call from google cloud it gives me an error saying:

```
RefreshError: Failed to retrieve http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/?recursive=true from the Google Compute Engine metadata service. Compute Engine Metadata server unavailable
```

[image]

[image]